# Why Flow can not infer type with default value of method parameter

Tags: javascript, flowtype

When you code this method:

```
   // @flow

   function greeting (name: string = 8): string {
    return `Hello ${name}!!`
   }
```

Flow check that default value is wrong, ok for me, but with this code:

```
   // @flow

   function greeting (name = 'world'): string {
    return `Hello ${name}!!`
   }

   greeting(8)
```

there is not an error with use a number argument, as i expect like that

```
   function greeting (name: string = 'world'): string {
    return `Hello ${name}!!`
   }
```

Why can not infer the type with the default value?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That's because in your example, the function returns a string, but there's no type stated for the `name` parameter.

Since you're interpolating `name` into a string, using backticks (``), its type will implicitly convert to string even if it's a number. 
So as long as you return a string - your notation is ok.

If you'd like flow to error, you can do the following:

```
function greeting (name: string = "name"): string {
    return `Hello ${name}!!`
   }
```

Then when you'll call it like so:

`greeting(8);`

you'll get the following error:

```
greeting(8)
            ^ Cannot call `greeting` with `8` bound to `name` because number [1] is incompatible with string [2].
References:
6: greeting(8)
            ^ [1]
2: function greeting (name: string = "name"): string {
```

The whole thing is around inference. 
Imagine the following case:

`function(name: string | number = "name") {..`
In this notation `name` can be either string or a number.

Flow has no way of knowing your intention with a default value, so it infers everything as `any`

Comment: Because defaults don't describe the type: you could easily do: `function(name: string | number = 'name')` So why should flow assume that it's anything but 'any'?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is about why ```function greeting (name = 'world'): string``` and  ```function greeting (name: string = 'world'): string``` is not the same. Why ```name = 'world' != name: string```? In typescript the type of the method parameter is inferred with the value.

Comment: The whole thing is around inference. 
Imagine the following case: `function(name: string | number = "name")...`
In this notation name can be either string or a number.
Flow has no way of knowing your intention with a default value, so it infers everything as `any`.